# Implementing SeekBar in Android in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, json, seekbar

In my application I am trying to implement SeekBar.. The SeekBar is working fine when playing the sound at first time. but When I click the button to play the sound again then I am an endless loop of errors regarding the **MediaPlayer**. The thing that I want is that when I while playing the sound if I click the the play button the sound should play again from the beginning and the SeekBar should also start from beginning. If I remove the the SeekBar then everything is working fine.. But SeekBar is must in my application.. I have implemented all these things in the BaseAdapter.. I have to do all the things in the **BaseAdapter**. So please help me in letting me the code that works with the **BaseAdapter**..

This is my code... Please have a look...

```
mediaPlayer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Loading Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mp.reset();
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource("url for any mp3 audio file");
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp.prepareAsync();
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mp.start();
                        mediaPlayer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.m_pause);
                        seekBar.setProgress(0);
                        seekBar.setMax(100);
                        mUpdateTimeTask = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                                   long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                                   int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
                                   seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                                   mHandler.post(this);
                            }
                        });
                        mUpdateTimeTask.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mediaPlayer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.m_play);
                mp.stop();
                try {
                    mUpdateTimeTask.join();
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            }
        });
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
                    mUpdateTimeTask = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                               long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                               int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
                               //timer.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
                               seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                               mHandler.post(this);
                        }
                    });
                    mUpdateTimeTask.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                }
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                }
                else
                {
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                }
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        mp.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your BaseAdapter which sets the current seekbarprogress to zero

```
void setSeekBarValuetoZero(){  
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
}
```

Please check the initially that seekbar is initialized. 
You can call this function from yourMediaPlayer class before mp.reset();

Comment: I have created the method and called it before the mp.reset(); but nothing happens.. I am still facing the endless errors...

Comment: where are you adding sound? where it goes in endless loop??

Comment: in the logcat i am getting endless errors.... and I am adding the sound in the mp.setDataSource();

Comment: everytime you need progress to be zero then y dont you set value of seekbar in mp.setDataSource();?

Comment: how can i set the value of seekBar in mp.setDataSource();??

Comment: lot of things are not clear to me in this,,one is where is initalization of seekbar ,,,ya above thing wsnt upto the mark,,,
you can paste your code or can send me link where i can get it then i ll try to fix the problm..